# SUMO GUI and TraCI problem: Could not connect to TraCI sever using port xxxxx ( TraCI server already finished)

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, virtualenv, sumo

I am trying to run `sumo-gui` with using `TraCI` and when I ran program file
the error occurred and cannot run. (I'm using virtual environment)

[image]

It works without `sumo-gui` but I want to see the visualized data.
Can anybody help me?

My code (run by _step function):

```
class SumoEnvironment_basic(MultiAgentEnv):

    def __init__(self, net_file, route_file,cfg_file, 
           out_csv_name=None, use_gui=True, num_seconds=20000, 
           delta_time=5, yellow_time=3, min_green=5, max_green=50, 
           single_agent=False):

        self._net = net_file
        self._route = route_file
        self._config = cfg_file
        self.use_gui = use_gui
        if self.use_gui:
            self._sumo_binary = sumolib.checkBinary('sumo-gui')
        else:
            self._sumo_binary = sumolib.checkBinary('sumo')

        ......
        ......

def _step(self):

        self.metrics = []
        sumo_cmd = [self._sumo_binary,
                     "-n", self._net,
                     "-r", self._route,
                     "-c", self._config                     
                     ]
        if self.use_gui:
            sumo_cmd.extend(['--start'])

        traci.start(sumo_cmd)
        ......
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "cannot open display", so this is probably not on your local machine but you are using ssh to some remote server? You can try to do X forwarding with `ssh -X`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed problem.

To someone who has same problem,
the problem was using Linux gui in windows.
So I downloaded X11 server, VSCXrv and it worked.
download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

Thank you for reading :)